# How do you use the setblock command in Minecraft Windows 10 edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to use the `setblock` command, but it won't work. I tried `set block x y z x y z`, but it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `setblock` is this:

```
setblock <position: x y z> <tileName: Block> [tileData: int] [replace|destroy|keep]
```

If you’re not doing the command in a command block, you need a `/` before `setblock`.

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/setblock):

> **Arguments**

> position: x y z
> Specifies the position of the block to be changed. May use tilde notation to specify a position relative to the command's execution.

> tileName: Block
> Specifies the new block. Must be a block id (for example, `stone`).

> tileData: int (optional)
> Specifies additional data to further describe the new block. Must be between 0 and 15 (inclusive). If not specified, defaults to 0.

> replace|destroy|keep (optional)
> Specifies how to handle the block change. Must be one of:

> - destroy — The old block drops both itself and its contents (as if
>   destroyed by a player). Plays the appropriate block breaking noise.
> - keep — Only air blocks will be changed (non-air blocks will be "kept").
> - replace — The old block drops neither itself nor any
>   contents. Plays no sound.

> If not specified, defaults to replace.

For example, if you want to place a stone block at the coordinates 4, 3, 53 you would do this:

```
 /setblock 4 3 53 stone
```

If you wanted to place orange wool (data value is 1) 3 blocks above you, you would do this:

```
/setblock ~ ~3 ~ wool 1
```